# Import XML file into SQL Server without BULK

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, import

I'm trying to import data from a XML file into a database. I've made a test script using `BULK INSERT`, but when I've tested on the live database, permissions for `BULK` are disabled.

***Attempt #1:***

```
BULK INSERT XMLTable FROM 'C:\Radu\test.xml' WITH (ROWTERMINATOR = '>');
```

[image]

So, I have continued research to find a way to avoid using `BULK` and found other options, such as `OPENROWSET` and `OPENDATASOURCE`. But unfortunately, rights for these operations are also revoked.

***Attempt #2:***

```
SELECT * 
FROM   OPENROWSET('MSDASQL',  
'Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.xml)};DefaultDir=C:\Radu\test.xml;', 
'SELECT * FROM [test.xml];' )
```

resulted in an error:

```
Msg 15281, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
SQL Server blocked access to STATEMENT 'OpenRowset/OpenDatasource' of component 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server. A system administrator can enable the use of 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' by using sp_configure. For more information about enabling 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', see "Surface Area Configuration" in SQL Server Books Online.
```

I've tried to `RECONFIGURE` the permissions for this, but with no success.

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
EXEC sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
```

also resulted in:

```
Msg 15247, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_configure, Line 94
User does not have permission to perform this action.
Msg 5812, Level 14, State 1, Line 2
You do not have permission to run the RECONFIGURE statement.
Msg 15123, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_configure, Line 51
The configuration option 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' does not exist, or it may be an advanced option.
Msg 5812, Level 14, State 1, Line 4
You do not have permission to run the RECONFIGURE statement.
```

I'm still trying to find a solution just to import the information into the database, I don't need a special format, just to get the data in the system, although ideally I would like to import each xml line as a record in my table.

It appears that most of my options are cut off, so I would very much appreciate any suggestions.

**UPDATE:**

I am going to create a stored procedure to import this data, so ideally this would be generic, no hardcoding with the XML information.

Comment: Do you have any front end code like C# etc or Sql Management Screen to do the same

Comment: @AmitRanjan No, unfortunately I have to do everything from queries.

Comment: Ok then see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

For BULK INSERT operation, you need administrator privileges for that database. You can take XML data in XML variable and insert into table as mentioned in this link :

[Import 'xml' into Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838627/import-xml-into-sql-server)

Comment: I'm trying to do this generic, because I will have a stored procedure which will import the data.

Comment: Can you pass XML string as parameter in SP ?

Comment: The number of characters is limited and the XML files have in at least 100.000 characters.

Comment: I think you can pass string in NVARCHAR(MAX) type variable and take XML from it, no ?

Comment: Yes, the parameter of the SP could read all the characters, but the frontend part where I would input the parameter's value is limited (it's a textbox)

Comment: Ideally I would pass to the stored procedure the path to the file to be imported.

Comment: Textbox for XML ? I think you taking XML file path in textbox. You just read xml from that path and pass it in string.

Comment: Well, that is what I was trying, sending the PATH of the XML file and appending the PATH to the stored procedure `BULK INSERT` command and executing it. But, as I have said, I have no permissions to use `BULK`.

Comment: No, I am not telling to pass path of XML. You just read XML from that path in C# code and pass data as string in SP parameter.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. But I am limited only to using SQL. I have an application for which I'm doing data layer maintenance only, and the only tools available ar those for the database.

Answer (score 0):

Since you dont have bulk upload permissions then you need some tool to convert the XML into XSLX or XSL then open it and copy all the rows and paste it in the table.

Or

This still uses a bulk load component, try it, if it get worked.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316005